# FFmpeg buffering before write

Tags: ffmpeg

I have written a working audio transcoder using the new [FFmpeg API](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavc__encdec.html).

As documented, the following behavior occurs:

> At the beginning of decoding or encoding, the codec might accept
>   multiple input frames/packets without returning a frame...

This buffering can be on the order of 200ms before the write callback is invoked. Is there any easy way to tell FFmpeg to always immediately process and write all available data, or to adjust the internal buffer sizes?

Comment: You better check for specific codec info's (that you intend to use) and look for low latency settings.